# Android application and myBatis

Tags: android, sqlite, ibatis, mybatis

I'd like to use myBatis (iBatis 3) in an Android application.  Has anyone tried such a thing or know of any resources for this?

Answer (score 5):

aBatis is a data mapper framework available for Android 
 
　that couples objects with stored procedures or 
 
　SQL statements using an XML descriptor or annotations.
 
aBatis is like an Android equivalent of iBatis.
 

 
---simple & light ORM library like iBatis for Web development
 
--carrying ibatis's feature
 
--easy-to-use as iBatis
 
--shorten a development period
 
--independent of development phase
 
--Android sdk1.6 and up

http://sonixlabs.com/abatis/

Comment: Is aBatis still active? Source changes are from 2011 only?

Answer (score 4):

The first thing to do in order to do that is to compile myBatis for Dalvik. But it's likely to be too heavy for a device like a smartphone.

If you are looking for a lightweight persistence layer, you could look at Ammentos:

http://www.ammentos.org/

Same trouble: you will need to compile it for Dalvik.

Existing ORMs for Android:

http://ormlite.sourceforge.net/sqlite_java_android_orm.html

https://www.activeandroid.com/

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer myBatis because it's so efficient and I have control over the SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use lightweight lib in android apps like [greenDAO](http://greendao-orm.com/) or Ormlite, greenDAO is an open source project to help Android developers working with data stored in SQLite. SQLite is an awesome embedded relational database. However, developing for it requires alot of additional work. Writing SQL and parsing query results are quite tedious tasks. greenDAO will do the work for you: it maps Java objects to database tables (often called ORM). This way you can store, update, delete, and query for Java objects using a simple object oriented API. Save time and focus on real problems!
greenDAO’s primary design goals

- Maximum performance (probably the fastest ORM for Android)
- Easy to    use APIs    Highly optimized for Android    Minimal memory
  consumption
- Small library size, focus on the essentials

Answer (score -2):

I create simple android project that using mybatis

check this: https://github.com/gustaroska/HijrDroid